# Java Regex - Match multiple lines that don't end with character

Tags: java, regex

If the data spans multiple lines it will end with "**;**" but there may be comment text which includes "**;**".

```
This is test
b=4
/* a=b+c; */
b=5
c=7
/* a=b-c; */
a=b*c;
```

I tried with this regex.

```
(This is test).+?;
```

It returns

```
This is test
b=4
/* a=b+c;
```

I want to know correct regex for whole match of the text.

Comment: sorry, the question a little a confuse, can you put a example the input and what do you expect?

Comment: You should write a parser.  What are you going to do about `for(i = 1; i < 10; i++)` and other similar statements.  And then you have statements in block comments (as shown) and line comments (`//`).

Comment: It looks very much like you're applying the wrong solution to whatever it is you need to do, so: what do you _actually_ need to do? E.g. "I have a text file and need to find .... in it", not  "I want to apply a regex", because that's something you do to solve a problem, not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you trying to ignore the line-breaks and define `;` as your custom line terminator, it is best to use [`String#split(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-). Try the following pattern:

```
\;(?!\s*\*\/)
```

If I use it with your string:

```
String str = "This is test"
+"\nb=4"
+"\n/* a=b+c; */"
+"\nb=5\nc=7"
+"\n/* a=b-c; */"
+"\na=b*c;";

for(String s : str.split("\\;(?!\\s*\\*\\/)")) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

I get the following output:

```
This is test
b=4
/* a=b+c; */
b=5
c=7
/* a=b-c; */
a=b*c
```